# EMF compare tool cannot identify 'nestedClassifier' when comparing UML model

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf-compare

We attempt to use EMF compare tool in Eclipse for comparing the following UML model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xmi:XMI xmi:version="20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701" xmlns:CDA="http://www.openhealthtools.org/mdht/schemas/cda/4" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML">
      <uml:Package xmi:id="PackageId" name="PackageA">
         <nestedClassifier xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="nestedClassifierId" name="nestedClassifier">
            <ownedComment xmi:id="ownedCommentId">
              <body>Body of the article.</body>
            </ownedComment>
         </nestedClassifier>
      </uml:Package>
    </xmi:XMI>
```

By following the EMF compare documentation: http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/documentation/latest/developer/developer-guide.html#Comparison_Scope
We wrote the following class for the UML comparison:

```
 import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.compare.Comparison;
import org.eclipse.emf.compare.Diff;
import org.eclipse.emf.compare.EMFCompare;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resource.UMLResource;

public class EMFcompare {
    EList<Diff> differences;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // compare two models which are exactly the same
        Comparison comparison = compare("./models/MinimalModel.uml", "./models/MinimalModel.uml");

        // output the comparison result
        System.out.println(comparison.getDifferences().size());
        for (Diff diff : comparison.getDifferences()) {
            System.out.println("Diff");
            System.out.println("Kind is " + diff.getKind());
            System.out.println("State: " + diff.getState());
            System.out.println(diff);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    public static Comparison compare(String uml1, String uml2) {
        // create uri for loading resource set 
        URI uri1 = URI.createFileURI(uml1);
        URI uri2 = URI.createFileURI(uml2);

        // Register the UML format for model comparison
        Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("uml", UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);

        // Load resource sets
        ResourceSet resourceSet1 = new ResourceSetImpl();
        ResourceSet resourceSet2 = new ResourceSetImpl();
        resourceSet1.getResource(uri1, true);
        resourceSet2.getResource(uri2, true);

        // Compare output uml model with the expected uml model
        Comparison comparison = EMFCompare.builder().build().compare(EMFCompare.createDefaultScope(resourceSet1, resourceSet2, null));

        return comparison;
    }
}
```

In the class, we loaded the same UML model twice, therefore, the two models in comparison are exactly the same. However, the output result indicates that there are some differences between the two models:

```
2
Diff
Kind is ADD
State: UNRESOLVED
AttributeChangeSpec{attribute=AnyType.mixed, value=body=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.impl.AnyTypeImpl@cd2dae5 (mixed: [ecore.xml.type:text=Body of the article.], anyAttribute: null), kind=ADD, source=LEFT, state=UNRESOLVED}
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Diff
Kind is DELETE
State: UNRESOLVED
AttributeChangeSpec{attribute=AnyType.mixed, value=body=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.impl.AnyTypeImpl@53f65459 (mixed: [ecore.xml.type:text=Body of the article.], anyAttribute: null), kind=DELETE, source=LEFT, state=UNRESOLVED}
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The expected output should indicate that there is no differences between two UML models. It seems like that EMF compare doesnt support 'nestedClassifier' comparison. Is there any method we could use to improve our EMF comparison class to resolve this problem?